# Executing Functions Between Two Child Components Svelte

Tags: javascript, electron, svelte, ace-editor

I'm working on an Electron project using Svelte for the frontend. I'm relatively new to Svelte. So here is the problem, I have a parent component named `MainContent.svelte` and two child components `editor.svelte` and `preview.svelte`. The Editor and Preview are both placed in the MainContent component. What I want to do is when the content of the Editor is changed, I want to update the Preview pane to reflect those changes. I previously had done this same project using Vanilla JavaScript but thought of using Svelte as it was easier to manage the project.

There is function which listens for any changes in the Editor pane and another function to update the Preview pane. But what I can't wrap my head around is how to call the function to update the Preview when the Editor content changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a property and lift the state up to the main component, you can still use functions internally if you have to, e.g.

```html
<script>
  // ...
  let content = '...';
</script>

<Editor bind:content />
<Preview {content} />
```

If the preview needs to update via a function you can call that in a reactive statement:

```html
<script>
  // ...
  export let content;

  $: updatePreview(content);
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'll definitely try it.